# Insert a function in a class

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, ecmascript-6, mongoose-schema

I need to integrate a code of a colleague into my website. I don't know why he decided to write the database in a class and asynchronous style, because i don't think it is necessary. Anyway, it is not harmful:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
class User {
    constructor() {
        this.user = mongoose.model('user', {
            email: String,
            password: String,
            hash: String,
            salt: String,
        })
    }

    checkEmailPassword(email, password) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.user.find({email, password}, {}, (err, users) => {
                if(err) throw(err)
                if(users.length > 0) resolve(users[0])
                else reject('not found')
            })
        })
    }

    addAccountWOCheck(userInf, way) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var collection = new this.user(userInf)
            // collection.setPassword(userInf.password)
            collection.save((err, data) => {
                if (err) throw (err)
                else resolve(data)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Now, I want to add a `setPassword` function that encrypts `password`. I want the function to be called by a user instance rather than the class, like `collection.setPassword(thePassWord)` rather than `this.user.setPassword(...)` in `addAccountWOCheck`, but I don't know how to insert this function to this class

```
setPassword = function(email) {
    var salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, 'SHA1').toString('hex');
}
```

Could anyone help?

**Edit 1:**

I tried to add inside the class:

```
setPassword(collection) {
    collection.hash = "abc";
    console.log("setPassword: " + JSON.stringify(collection));
}
```

and call in `addAccountWOCheck`:

```
var collection = new this.user(userInf)
this.setPassword(collection)
collection.save((err, data) => {
    if (err) throw (err)
    else resolve(data)
})
```

I can see `setPassword` is called, but `collection` is not modified in the database.

Comment: who is "he"? ;)

Comment: Why not just add the method with exactly the same syntax as the existing methods `checkEmailPassword` and `addAccountWOCheck`? Have you tried that? Have you asked your colleague who wrote the class?

Comment: Because each time before modifying a user, it needs to find the user first. But, i want to work directly on a user.

Comment: @SoftTimur Yes - those other methods do work on `User` *instances* as well. They're not `static` method. I'm not sure what you mean by "*it needs to find the user first*" - when invoking a method on the instance, don't you have a user already?

Comment: @Bergi "it needs to find the user first" means we have to do eg, `this.user.find({email})` in `checkEmailPassword`. I don't see how to directly work on an instance, eg, how to directly call a function of `collection`?

Comment: Yes, you probably have to do the same thing in your `setPassword` function. But that doesn't matter for the syntax of how and where to put `setPassword`.

Comment: I don't understand why we can NOT work directly on an instance like `collection` in `addAccountWOCheck`.

Comment: @SoftTimur `collection` is an instance of the mongoose model, not of your `User` class.

Comment: I'd expect it to work in Edit 1. Though class design is pretty much useless. `this` state doesn't matter, and these should be static methods. Also, `save` returns a promise and doesn't need to be promisified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `Edit 1` works

add the function inside the class:

```
setPassword(collection) {
    collection.hash = "abc";
    console.log("setPassword: " + JSON.stringify(collection));
}
```

and call in `addAccountWOCheck`:

```
var collection = new this.user(userInf)
this.setPassword(collection)
collection.save((err, data) => {
    if (err) throw (err)
    else resolve(data)
})
```

The reason why it did not successfully update the `hash` of `collection` previously is that I forgot to add `hash` field in the user schema (unlike what I posted in OP).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for [`prototype`. Here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp) is a detailed explanation of how you can add more functionality to an existing object.

Below example might help:

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
}
Person.prototype.name = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};
```

> #### JavaScript Prototypes
>
> All JavaScript objects inherit the properties
>   and methods from their prototype.
>
> Objects created using an object literal, or with new Object(), inherit
>   from a prototype called Object.prototype.
>
> Objects created with new Date() inherit the Date.prototype.
>
> The Object.prototype is on the top of the prototype chain.
>
> All JavaScript objects (Date, Array, RegExp, Function, ....) inherit
>   from the Object.prototype.

Comment: prototypes are implemented on existing JS objects, check the `JavaScript Prototypes` block I just updated in the answer section.

Comment: Sorry, could you tell me concretely what to do with my `collection` and `setPassword`?